# Using the Web Crypto API from Firefox AddOn

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can't figure out how to access the Web Crypto API from an AddOn script itself (no documentation).

Trying to do it from a content-script gives a permission error accessing `then`:

```
JavaScript error:
  resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js ->
  resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> 
  resource://..../data/content-script.js,
  line 36: Error: Permission denied to access property "then"
```

The relevant code is:

```
  var password = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode('password');
  var salt = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode('salt');
  var iterations = 1;
  var outputLen = 20;
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw", password, {"name": "PBKDF2"}, false, ["deriveKey"]
  ).then(function(baseKey) {
    return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
      { "name": "PBKDF2",
        "salt": salt,
        "iterations": iterations,
        "hash": "SHA-1",
      },
      baseKey,                              // input key
      {"name": "AES-CBC", "length": 32*8},  // output key use and size
      true,                                 // output key is extractable
      ["encrypt","decrypt"]);               // output key capabilities
  }).then(function(aesKey) {
    return window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", aesKey);
  }).then(function(keyBytes) {
    var keyArray = Array.slice(new Uint8Array(keyBytes), 0, outputLen);
    keyArray.toHex = toHex;
    keyArray.toPassword = toPassword;
    return keyArray;
  });
```

Is there any `require` the Web Crypto API into add-ons, or is there anything else I can do to make this work? I don't really want to use a JS crypto library due to runtime concerns (PBKDF2 runs fast → choose more iterations → more secure).

Comment: If anyone else is stumbling upon this page because of this bug: Error: Permission denied to access property "then" I filed a bug report for it and it got promptly fixed, thanks to Tim Taubert and and Boris Zbarsky. The fix will be shipped in Firefox 47. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250930

Comment: @ClareT: Could you make your comment into an answer? This information should be more prominent than a comment, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Components.utils.importGlobalProperties(['crypto']);
var blah = crypto.subtle.deriveKey({....});
```

Taken from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.importGlobalProperties

Comment: Note that this is only supported in Firefox 37+

Comment: Thanks @Luckyrat I didn't know that, what would be the pre37 way? Is importing global proprety of TextEndoder/TextDecoder also FF37+ or just crypto?

Comment: I don't think there was a way - I certainly couldn't find one. I think Mozilla must have just forgotten to enable the import of crypto when they launched the CryptoAPI. Not sure about those other properties but I know some worked before FF37 because I used IndexedDB quite a few versions ago. I used to do some ctypes for crypto but recent FF versions have introduced massive performance regressions with that so I had to switch to WebCrypto and a fall-back to the slower sjcl for FF36 and lower. https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/issues/356 has all the gory details if you're interested.

Comment: Ah maybe `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` is only solution pre FF36 then huh?

Comment: Yeah maybe. I've not found the hiddenDOMWindow to be reliable when accessed from JSMs though - I think you have to delay any access to the hiddenDOMWindow until a late stage of Firefox startup. For user-initiated crypto operations it might work but I was looking for something service oriented so waiting around for a window to be created wasn't an option. As far as this question is concerned, I'm not certain where SDK content scripts fit into the picture but I think they can only be executed once at least one window exists so hiddenDOMWindow would then be available at all times.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, we have to attach load listener on startup of your addon to hiddenDOMWindow, as if its not loaded then its not possible to use.

Comment: Hey @Luckyrat i was trying to update the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.importGlobalProperties i was adding a 2nd column to that table of atob, btoa, etc. In that column i was putting the firefox version from which it can be imported. Can you please help me figure out which min firefox version for each object? (somehting like this but just for gecko: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility )

Comment: Rather than a 2nd column, it might be better to put small tags on the ones we actually know about (similar to the "Firefox 29" example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules ). I think the only way to be sure which ones work in which version of Firefox/Gecko is to try them all - e.g. using a test JSM script like this: https://gist.github.com/luckyrat/7803415810fb4c09c975. I've not got time at the moment to try that out in all versions but for a start I can say rtcIdentityProvider becomes available in FF 38. All others are available by FF37 at the latest.

Comment: Thanks very much @Luckyrat for that script I'll try to run it on some channels :) is it ok to run that from non-jsm, so like mainthread? I don't see any issues

Comment: Yeah it should be fine, although I thought the global properties were already available in the main thread. From the looks of the current docs, it is also relevant from within a framescript context but I doubt it's much easier to run from there than from a jsm. Sadly, just running it directly from within something like the scratchpad won't be much help because the properties are already automatically imported into that scope.

Comment: @Luckyrat Are you sure though? I've been running from scratchpad and the errors for the non-existing ones are still happening. I'm just wondering if i screwed up cuz i launched up all my old builds but it was a one time thing as they all auto updated now :(

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I was oversimplifying. For the quick test script I wrote in the gist, you are probably right that it works from scratchpad but for the more complex one I started with (to actually test whether the imported properties worked) it wouldn't be a fair test unless run from a jsm. Given that I didn't have time to write a full test of each property and have just assumed they will work if they get imported, that point is moot. So lets stick with that assumption and just run them from scratchpad to save time :-)

Comment: Ahhh phew!!! I was worried I missed by chances haha I got down till Fx30 but couldnt get 29, 31, 32, 35, or 36. Since Fx38 has everything we dont need to go above it. But we should go down to min version till everything is unavailable.

Comment: I found this when looking for a way to quickly get lots of old versions installed: http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/ I have not yet installed it so can't vouch for its safety or reliability. My plan is to fire up a VM and dedicate it to hosting a dozen or so of the most recent builds to aid add-on testing. Probably won't get around to that for a couple of weeks though.

Comment: I've filled in the gaps down to FF28 (gist comments updated) but we're talking over a year ago now and before the latest supported ESR so I think going further back will be less valuable.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was so needed! I'll update MDN! :)